# Wordpress did not allow to save a new page

Tags: mysql, wordpress

After a wordpress migration from Windows to Ubuntu posts and pages are not saved. It shows an error after pressing "publish" or "Save draft" saying I did not have permissions to edit the page.

It also happens when I tried to upload a file in the "media" admin option, it saids something when wrong try later.

What I tried:

1. Disable plugins and using another theme. Not work.
2. Install Health check and show the error, the only critical error it shows me is:

Error: [] cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

3. I installed another fresh site in the same server but is workig fine, so is not server related
4. As I said it must be something in the database (mysql) that goes wrong in the migration, after searching the only issue could be causing the problem is that wp-config is:

   define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4' );

and in the database DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME is:

```
latin1
```

Is this an issue that can cause the error ?

-------------EDIT------------

A. I installed query monitor and after pressing save draf it shows the below error:
Call stack:

wp_die()

wp-admin/includes/post.php:257

edit_post()

wp-admin/post.php:227

B. The migration process was very simple:

B.1 I get and .sql which I restored using command line

B.2 I unzip the wordpress files and set permissions in ubuntu

B.3 Manually I change a value in a database column site_url and from old.com to new site.com

Comment: Exactly how did you migrate the site? Be specific and describe every step taken.

Comment: The problem was as a missing auto increment. Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929245/wordpress-cant-write-to-db-after-migration